# Latex file generate error in IEEE transaction class

Tags: bibliographies, errors, ieeetran, back-referencing

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\hyphenation{Smart Grid}
\begin{document}


\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{1}
Energy Reports. Available online: http://www.enerdata.net/enerdatauk/press-and-publication/energyfeatures/
enerfuture-2007.php (accessed on 10 January 2020).
\bibitem{2}
Costanzo, Giuseppe Tommaso, Guchuan Zhu, Miguel F. Anjos, and Gilles Savard. "A system architecture for autonomous demand side load management in smart buildings." IEEE Transactions on Smart Grid 3, no. 4 (2012): 2157-2165.

\bibitem{GH}
Nadeem Javaid, Ghulam Hafeez, Sohail Iqbal, Nabil Alrajeh, Mohamad Souheil Alabed, and Mohsen Guizani. ``Energy efficient integration of renewable energy sources in the smart grid for demand side management.'' IEEE Access 6 (2018): 77077-77096.
\bibitem{DR1}
Rastegar, Mohammad, and Mahmud Fotuhi-Firuzabad. "Outage management in residential demand response programs." IEEE transactions on smart grid 6, no. 3 (2014): 1453-1462.

\bibitem{DR2}
Fernandes, Filipe, Hugo Morais, Zita Vale, and Carlos Ramos. "Dynamic load management in a smart home to participate in demand response events." Energy and Buildings 82 (2014): 592-606.
\bibitem{ahmad19}
Ahmad, Ashfaq, and Jamil Khan. "Real-time Load Scheduling and Storage Management for Solar Powered Network Connected EVs." IEEE Transactions on Sustainable Energy (2019).
\bibitem{Yousefi}
Yousefi, Mojtaba, Amin Hajizadeh, and Mohsen Norbakhsh Soltani. "A Comparison Study on Stochastic Modeling Methods for Home Energy Management System." IEEE Transactions on Industrial Informatics (2019).
\bibitem{Jiang}
Jiang, Xin, and Chunyan Xiao. "Household Energy Demand Management Strategy Based on Operating Power by Genetic Algorithm." IEEE Access 7 (2019): 96414-96423.
\bibitem{Essa}
Al Essa, Mohammed Jasim M. "Home energy management of thermostatically controlled loads and photovoltaic-battery systems." Energy 176 (2019): 742-752.



\bibitem{Pipattanasomporn}
Pipattanasomporn, Manisa, Murat Kuzlu, and Saifur Rahman. "An algorithm for intelligent home energy management and demand response analysis." IEEE Transactions on Smart Grid 3, no. 4 (2012): 2166-2173.
\bibitem{Gonçalves}
Gonçalves, Ivo, Álvaro Gomes, and Carlos Henggeler Antunes. "Optimizing the management of smart home energy resources under different power cost scenarios." Applied Energy 242 (2019): 351-363.
%%Ahmad, Ashfaq, Nadeem Javaid, Mohsen Guizani, Nabil Alrajeh, and Zahoor Ali Khan. "An accurate and fast converging short-term load forecasting model for industrial applications in a smart grid." IEEE Transactions on Industrial Informatics 13, no. 5 (2016): 2587-2596.

\end{thebibliography}{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to the actual error message: A url should be enclosed in the `\url` command. This command is either provided by the `url` or the `hyperref` package.

Comment: `\bibitem{Gonçalves}` you can only use ascii letters  in the internal cite key but you have ç and also seem to be using the OT1 encoding.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I have edited my comment to reflect that.